# Passing arguments to context manager

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass arguments using context manager? Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
async with self.request.app['expiration_lock']('param'):
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'OrderStatusLock' object is not callable
```

Class OrderStatusLock:

```
class OrderStatusLock(_ContextManagerMixin, Lock):
    def __init__(self, *args, loop=None):
        print(args)
        self._waiters = None
        self._locked = False
        if loop is None:
            self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
        else:
            self._loop = loop

    async def acquire(self, *args):
        print('acq', args)
        if (not self._locked and (self._waiters is None or
                all(w.cancelled() for w in self._waiters))):
            self._locked = True
            return True

        if self._waiters is None:
            self._waiters = collections.deque()
        fut = self._loop.create_future()
        self._waiters.append(fut)
        try:
            try:
                await fut
            finally:
                self._waiters.remove(fut)
        except CancelledError:
            if not self._locked:
                self._wake_up_first()
            raise

        self._locked = True
        return True
```

And if it is possible, what issues I can face, using this? Thank you very much.

Comment: The instance of `OrderStatusLock` apparently stored in `self.request.app['expiration_lock']` does not have a `__call__` method (just as the class definition tells us), and thus cannot be called. Maybe you wanted to store the class itself instead of an instance, and construct it by passing `'param'`?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa thanks for your answer, I just need to pass some arguments to this. I have implemented __call__ method and it seems, that now I can pass them. Thanks))

Comment: You probably want the `__enter__()` method.

Comment: @brunns `__aenter__` since it is async context block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your question, and I don't know where your `_ContextManagerMixin` class comes from. I also don't know much about async.

However, here's a simple (non-async) demonstration of a pattern where an argument can be passed to a context manager that alters how the `__enter__` method of the context manager operates.

Remember: a context manager is, at its heart, just a class that implements an `__enter__` method and an `__exit__` method. The `__enter__` method is called at the start of the `with` block, and the `__exit__` method is called at the end of the `with` block.

The `__call__` method added here in my example class is called immediately before the `__enter__` method and, unlike the `__enter__` method, can be called with arguments. The `__exit__` method takes care to clean up the changes made to the class's internal state by the `__call__` method and the `__enter__` method.

```
from threading import Lock

class LockWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.food = ''

    def __enter__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print(f'{self.food} for breakfast, please!')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.lock.release()
        self.food = ''
        return True

    def __call__(self, spam_preferred: bool):
        if spam_preferred:
            self.food = 'Spam'
        else:
            self.food = 'Eggs'
        return self

breakfast_context_manager = LockWrapper()

with breakfast_context_manager(spam_preferred=True):    # prints 'Spam for breakfast, please!'
    pass

with breakfast_context_manager(spam_preferred=False):    # prints 'Eggs for breakfast, please!'
    pass
```

N.B. My example above will suppress all exceptions that are raised in the body of the `with` statement. If you don't want to suppress any exceptions, or if you only want to suppress certain kinds of exceptions, you'll need to alter the implementation of the `__exit__` method.

Note also that the return values of these functions are quite important. `__call__` has to return `self` if you want the class to be able to then call `__enter__`. `__enter__` has to return `self` if you want to be able to access the context manager's internal state in the body of the `with` statement. `__exit__` should return `True` if you want exceptions to be suppressed, and `False` if you want an encountered exception to continue to endure outside of the `with` statement.

You can find a good tutorial on context managers [here](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/). The tutorial also contains some info on how you might adapt the above pattern for async code using the `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods.